# Disable Chrome / Google Login synchronisation

Tags: google-chrome, browser, gmail, user-profiles

Is it possible to disable the synchronisation between Google Webpages and Chrome?

I mean: If you login to your gmail account you are also logged in Chrome and vice-versa. To be clear I don't ask if you can disable the password sync but indeed how you disable the "login sync".

Comment: There's no "login in Chrome". There's login in Google services and it's an all or nothing situation. Meaning: When you use Gmail, Youtube, Google Drive, etc. youŕe logged in all Google services and when you logoff you're then logged off of all Google services.

Comment: Not a "dude" and no longer here. Enough to say the sync feature is automatic in Chrome. Bye.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to offend you. Didn't looked at you're username...

Comment: +1 because this is a perfectly good question imo. Google very recently changed Chrome's behavior - logging into Chrome used to be optional (you only had to do it if you wanted sync), now it's automatic when you log into any Google service. See https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2018/09/23/why-im-leaving-chrome/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Chrome now logs you into the browser whenever you log into a google service.
You can disable this controversial feature by opening the following URL in Chrome:

chrome://flags/#account-consistency

Find the flag called "Identity consistency between browser and cookie jar" and set it to "Disabled". Note that there is no guarantee that this option will remain in the future.

Source:
https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17942723

Comment: Works great!  One strange outcome is that my user inside Chrome now shows up as "Saratoga" with a horse head?

Comment: I can't get this to work on Chrome for macOS

Comment: If you search by Strg+F, enter: `Identity consistency between browser and cookie jar`